# What's the convention for a directory to store unix domain sockets in?

Tags: unix

On Ubuntu or *nix systems is there a convention to store Unix Domain Socket files in a specific directory? I've seen applications store it in `/tmp`, but I thought `/tmp` can get periodically cleared, no?

Answer (score 0):

None other than the application creating a file in /tmp should remove the file. It's is somewhat common to offer the option to clear /tmp on boot, but this must be enabled by the administrator.

My distro will usually put sockets as well as pidfiles in /var/run/appname.

For reference:
[Gentoo Development Guide: Filesystem](http://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/filesystem/index.html)
[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)
[FreeBSD direcotry structure](http://www.no.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/dirstructure.html)

None of these tell you where to put sockets, but they all point to /var as a general purpose folder for stuff created by processes at runtime.